# Is it possible to solve a cubic convex obj function with Gurobi?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, math-software, python

is it possible for Gurobi to solve a optmization problem with a cubic convex objective function?
I only found, that it can solve "Quadratically Constrained Program (QCP)".
They didn't mentioned anything for the obj function. Does it mean quadratically constrained quadratic programming? 
Below is an example on how my problem looks like.

\begin{align}
& \min & \sum_{a \in A} |x_a|^3 + \sum_{v \in V} y_u^3 &&\\
%% & \text{subject to} &  x_a \cdot |x_a|= d  && \forall a \in A \\
& & y_u \geq 0 && \forall u \in V
\end{align}

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, give a good reference where we can learn what Gorubi is.

Comment: Sure, here it is:
http://www.gurobi.com/products/gurobi-optimizer

Comment: Your bigger problem is the constraint $x_a\cdot |x_a|=d$. How do you intend to render that in Gurobi?

Comment: Sorry, I think the constraint (I deleted it) isnt causing trouble since the d was fixed. But first of all I need to know if it is possible (and it would be awesome if you also know how) to solve the cubic convex objective wit gurobi. Any hints or ideas except the socp, that I dont really understand yet.

Answer (score 3):

To build a cubic, first note that (the rotated scalar Lorentz cone) $w^2 \leq u v$ can be written as the standard SOCP constraint $\left| \begin{pmatrix}2w\\u-
v\end{pmatrix} \right|_2 \leq u + v$

We now note that $s^3 \leq t$, with non-negative $s$, can be written as $s^4 \leq ts$, which we expand as $w^2 \leq ts$ and $s^2 \leq w$. Hence, SOCP-representable as those two are SOCP-representable.

Unfortunately, you have the constraint $x_a \cdot |x_a| = d$ which is nonconvex and thus not SOCP-representable.

EDIT: ...unless $d$ is fixed, as then you simply have a linear constraint $x_a = \text{sign}(d)\sqrt{|d|}$.

Comment: Thank you!
Okay, I dont really get how you change my objective to a socp. 
d is fixed, so it shouldnt be a problem.

But Im not sure how you change the first sum the variables that are not non-negative).
I cant see how the cubic term can be reduced.

Comment: The absolute values are non-negative, so you just add a new variable $-q \leq x \leq q$ (model absolute value) and use $q^3$ in the objective