# How to transform a cubic non convex problem into a quadratic convex problem

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, python, non-convex-optimization

I have the following cost function for portfolio allocation to be maximise:

$$
w^\top \mu-\frac{1}{2}\gamma w^\top \Sigma w+\frac{1}{6}\gamma^2 w^\top M_3(w\otimes w),
$$

which considers the co-skewness ($M_3$ tensor), $\gamma$ is the risk aversion (a constant), $w$ is the weight vector which is the quantity to estimate, $\Sigma$ is the covariance and $r$ the returns.

This function is cubic and non convex (I have not calculated the hessian but I think everytime the higher polynomial degree is 3 then is never convex..), so I cannot use the typical convex optimisation with cvxpy in python. However, it should be possible to transform/replace the cubic term with a quadratic term and adding a new constraint in order to have a quadratic form, which can be solved probably more easily.
Obviously if the transformation gives a convex quadratic form is better, but if it does not, also quadratic non-convex is fine as there are solvers for non-convex quadratic problems (Gurobi).

Can anyone help please to reformulate the above equation in order to make it quadratic?

Thanks

Comment: how do you know it's non-convex. and this is the first I heard of Gurobi, given that quadratic programming is a type of *convex* optimization. that software might only convert non-convex *constraints* to linear ones, not non-convex objective functions

Comment: I have not computed the hessian, so I cannot say to 100%, but I cannot think of any 3 degree polynonial which can be convex without additional contraints (for example x^3 with x>0, this is convex'), but if you have examples I am happy to be corrected of course..anyway the convexity is not my main concern..i need to solve that optimisation in python..so I need to either transform it to a convex quadratic to use cvxpy or find another way to do it..thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347553/is-it-possible-to-solve-a-cubic-convex-obj-function-with-gurobi

Comment: thanks..I am not sure in the end I have many constraints so I cannot really say whether my function is convex or not. I was thinking of going with a genetic algoritm which does not assume anything basically

Comment: which sources use heuristic optimization algorithms or genetic algorithm to maximize portfolio skewness?

Comment: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756

Comment: the article contains nothing about genetic algorithm or portfolio skewness. which page of it are you referring

Comment: Have you thought of using this alternative skewness measure. It looks convex https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59364/alternative-low-moment-measure-of-skewness